# How can I execute script after wordpress page contents fully loaded

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dom, plugins

I'm making a plugin for wordpress post page and I'm trying to detect div with id "matched". I can see the div with browser tools, however console throws the message that the div wasn't found. I think that's because script is loading before the page contents. How can I make it to load after the post contents has rendered?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    var question =  document.getElementById("matched");

    window.onload = function afterWebPageLoad() { 
    
        if(question){
            console.log("id 'matched' exists");
        } else {
            console.log("id 'matched' not found");
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were calling `document.getElementById` before waiting for the page to load with the `onload` listener.

Move the variable declaration inside the `onload` listener so that it is only called when the page is loaded.

**What your code should look like:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

  window.onload = function afterWebPageLoad() {
    var question = document.getElementById("matched"); // <-- Moved inside
    
    if (question) {
      console.log("id 'matched' exists");
    } else {
      console.log("id 'matched' not found");
    }
  }
  
</script>

<p id="matched">match element</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` like this;

```js
let checker = setInterval(function () {
    if (document.getElementById("matched") !== null) {
        console.log("found")
        clearInterval(checker)
    } else {
        console.log("checking..")
    }
}, 100)
```

Also, you must check the element in `afterWebPageLoad` function. You must move question variable to the function.