# How to change the background colors of all <em> elements

Tags: javascript, element, italic

I am trying to change the background colors of all italized text, instead of using a span on every single word through the paragraph.
It says `<em>` next to the italized text.
I have tried

```
$(".em").css({
    "background-color":"#d9f9f9",
});
```

or/and tried this:

```
var elem=document.getElementByTagName(em)[1];
elem.style.backgroundColor='#d9f9f9';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
const italics = document.querySelectorAll('em');

italics.forEach(italic => {
  italic.style.backgroundColor = '#d9f9f9';
});
```

Comment: The second option from Egil worked in the text editor. Don't know why it will not work in wordpress custom css and js plugin.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Wordpress, but typically you get problems if the code is run before the DOM is ready. Check out this post for wrapping the code in a window.onload: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68552671/how-can-i-execute-script-after-wordpress-page-contents-fully-loaded

Answer (score 1):

See [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

Notices this method return an array, so we should loop it:

```
var emList = document.querySelectorAll('em');

[].forEach.call(emList , function(em) {
  // do whatever
  em.style.color = "red";
});
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, but the one below from Egil worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your first suggestion says `".em"` where it should say `"em"`. Your seconds suggestion says `em` where it should say `"em"`.